# Generate link to table of contents from a headline in Org

Tags: emacs, org-mode

When I export my org file to HTML, it generates a table of contents from my headlines. However, I want every headline to have a link back to its entry in the table of content. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2014-01/msg00028.html

I realized what I need is a floating table of content. And `worg.css` provides just that: http://orgmode.org/worg/style/worg.css

This is an awesome CSS.